# History of cubit - Galilei, Kopernik, Newton

Tags: units, measurement

Can cubit from Galileo Galilei books " Dialogue Concerning the Two Chief World Systems", "Two New Sciences", Newtons "Philosophiae Naturalis Principia Mathematica" or Mikołaj Kopernik books convert to other units like feet, meter, inch or does 1 cubit own different value nowadays?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Issues regarding ancient measure systems are not easy to manage*...

Galileo Galilei, in [Discorsi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_New_Sciences), uses *braccia*; the "old" translation by Crew & Di Salvio uses: "cubits".

A [braccio](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braccio_(unit%C3%A0_di_misura)) in Florence was: 583 mm.

In ancient Rome:

> according to Vitruvius, a [cubit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubit#Ancient_Rome) was equal to $1 \frac 1 2$ Roman feet or 6 palm widths, which is 443.8 mm (17.47 in).

According to [Stillman Drake](https://books.google.it/books?id=c-nIrKjBqOwC) [footnote page 469], the *braccio* used by Galileo was 21 to 22 inches, i.e. between 533 and 558 mm; he translates it with [yard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yard), which is 914 mm (36 in).

In conclusion, we may say that a good approximation for Galilei's *braccio* is an half-meter.

---

Regarding Copernicus, the evaluation of ancient astronomers regarding the dimension of planets' orbits was expressed in *earth radii*, i.e. with a "relative" measure; thus, I think that you can hardly find in his works measures expressed in *cubits*.

---

Isaac Newton in the *Principia* uses [(Paris) feet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Units_of_measurement_in_France_before_the_French_Revolution#Length) [about 325 mm] and *inches*; see **Book 3**, *Prop.17, Th.15* for :

> And from these measures the circumference of the earth is found to be $123,249,600$ Paris feet, and its semidiameter $19,615,800$ feet, on the hypothesis that the earth is spherical.